# "В свои 60" в середине предложения выделяется запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

Вряд ли кто-нибудь из нас в свои 60 составит конкуренцию 20-летним моделям.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одной запятой быть не может. Либо обособлять (но тогда с двух сторон), либо не обособлять.

Нормальное написание - без запятых. Если очень хочется пустить "в свои 60" как присоединение, то обособить, думаю, можно. Если оформить в виде "в свои-то 60", то обособление будет более оправданным.